# Exclude subcontrol from taking JavaFX effect

Tags: javafx

Is it possible to e.g. exclude the text or graphics of a button from an effect which has been set to the button?

Comment: You could probably use a `StackPane` with your `Button`. Then set the `Button`s text to empty string. Next, add a `Label` to the `StackPane`. Now your `Button` should only show the effect and you text shouldn't.

Comment: Post your code.

Comment: A code example is pretty simple:
myButton.setEffect(myEffect);

Adding an extra node is a workaround - don't want to do this.

Comment: What effect are you using that's also effecting the text?

Comment: Lightning effect - white text color should not be affected